# Send an e-mail for an address on column L only if column G is Y

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Could you guys give me some help? I'm a total noob, so I would really appreciate your help :)

I'm trying to create a script for a spreadsheet that sends a message to an e-mail address on column `L` every time, on the same row, column `G` is `Y`.

For example:

If `G9` is edited to `Y`, then an e-mail is sent to address specified on `L9`.

Currently, I'm trying the script below but it is not working:

```
function onEditTrigger(e){
   var range = e.range;
   var intCol = range.getColumn();

   if (intCol == 7){
      var intRow = range.getRow();                              
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(intRow, 12, 11, 8);          
      var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();           

      MailApp.sendEmail(dataValues[0][0], "Notification", "Value in column C: " 
                                                             + dataValues[0][2]);
   }
}
```

**Error:**

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "send e-mail")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine but I can see a few issues.

1. You don't say but when you get the error are you using the debugger? Note that the event object `(e)` only receives information when the trigger is fired. i.e. if you try to use the debugger to test an `onEdit(e)` function no information is passed to `(e)` as the trigger hasn't been fired.
2. Have a read of the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) in particular the section about restrictions. It say's

> They [simple triggers] cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.

So for your script to work you need to go to Edit -> Current project's triggers and create an onEdit trigger

[image: onEdit trigger settings]