# Sending out email through google sheets with row fully complete

Tags: google-sheets, sendmail

I am trying to modify my code in a way that i can send an email based off the values in a specified row.

Problem: several people will be using this sheet at the same time while conducting sales and the script calls for sending an email with a set of rows not containing the 'if' value of email_sent. i would like to insert a line or something that will only send the email of the rows that have all criteria filled. i would also like to to protect the cells AFTER they are sent so that they can not be edited or deleted erroneously. lastly, i would like for users without google accounts to be able to trigger the script.

```
    `// This constant is written in column L for rows for which an email
 `// has been sent successfully.`
`var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";`

`function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:K2
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,3,12)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message  = Utilities.formatDate(row[1], "GMT" , "MM/dd/yyyy" );
    var message1 = row[2];    // third column
    var message2 = row[3];
    var message3 = row[4];
    var message4 = row[5];
    var message5 = row[6];
    var message6 = row[7];
    var message7 = row[8];
    var message8 = row[9];
    var message9 = Utilities.formatDate(row[10], "GMT" , "MM/dd/yyyy" );
    var emailSent = row[12];    // 12th column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "\nSale date: " + message + "\nCustomer: " + message1 + "\nJob: " + message2 + "\nLender: " + message3 + "\nAged inventory: " + message4 + "\nreplacing CAN: " + message5 + "\nChange option: " + message6 + "\nSource: " + message7 + "\nRealtor: " + message8 + "\nClosing: " + message9);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 12).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}`
```

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do it in one line using IFs and && but it would be bulky and time-consuming to maintain.

Instead, add a new function to test the row.

Add these three new lines around your `for` loop:

```
var bool;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
   bool = testData(data[i])
   if(bool){
```

And also add a brace to the end line of the function.

Add the function below to your script file.

```
function testData(data) {
    var bool = true;
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        if (!data[x]) {
            bool = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return bool;
}
```

It works by passing the row to the test function. If any cell is blank it will return a false and the `function sendEmails2()` will then skip that row and move to the next row.

**UPDATE** Full working code

```
  // This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
  // has been sent successfully.
  var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

  function sendEmails2() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells A2:K2
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,3,12)
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
     if(testData(data[i])){ // Pass the row of data to the testData function (testData will return true or false)
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
      var message  = Utilities.formatDate(row[1], "GMT" , "MM/dd/yyyy" );
      var message1 = row[2];    // third column
      var message2 = row[3];
      var message3 = row[4];
      var message4 = row[5];
      var message5 = row[6];
      var message6 = row[7];
      var message7 = row[8];
      var message8 = row[9];
      var message9 = Utilities.formatDate(row[10], "GMT" , "MM/dd/yyyy" );
      var emailSent = row[11];    // 12th column
      if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
        var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "\nSale date: " + message + "\nCustomer: " + message1 + "\nJob: " + message2 + "\nLender: " + message3 + "\nAged inventory: " + message4 + "\nreplacing CAN: " + message5 + "\nChange option: " + message6 + "\nSource: " + message7 + "\nRealtor: " + message8 + "\nClosing: " + message9);
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 12).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    }
   }
  }


  function testData(data) { // Function to test the data 
      for (var x = 0; x < data.length - 1; x++) { // Loop through each cell (length -1 because we don't want to check the email sent cell as that should be empty)
          if (!data[x]) { // If a cell is empty return false
              return false;
          }
      }
      return true; // If no empty cells are found return true
  }
```

Comment: will it matter where i add these lines?

Comment: i received an error stating testData is not a function, it is undefined

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jDnt3E2Vy-HjJjysacdabK1usJCY_0YWx3drIi2Xmq0/edit#gid=0

this is the actual one im working on.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly! :)

Comment: No problem. Please accept my answer by clicking on the green tick beside the question.

Comment: i have 2 follow-ups

1. how do i protect the cells from being edited after the email has been sent for that row?
2. can i let users that are not signed in to a google account to trigger the mailapp script?

Comment: 1. Using sheet protections (Data -> Protected sheets and ranges) select the column and set permissions to 'Only you' and you can set a second protection to show a warning when editing the range. This will prevent you from deleting it accidentally. 2. Yes, create a trigger to run the script, you can create an 'On edit' trigger or a timed trigger (timed would be better IMO), [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100256/send-an-e-mail-for-an-address-on-column-l-only-if-column-g-is-y/44105011#44105011)

Comment: nice! i actually figured out the timed trigger on my own! it was one of the Aha! moments lol. as for the protection, i would like this to be automated and only AFTER the email is sent...

Comment: Ah good,  those Aha moments are the ones where you learn the most I find! O sorry I miss understood, you want to apply the protection the row of data after the email is sent? Please update your question with these questions added as it will help other people without having to read through all the comments.

Comment: Any help? PLEASE

Comment: Any help with what?

Comment: i need to protect the rows that are sent after theyre sent so that no one else has the ability to edit those rows.